# Accessing an item in a collection where the key is in a certain range

Tags: java, collections

I'd like to store some data in a collection for animation purposes, the idea being that the animation data is stored in key frames. To work out where you are in the animation you need to know what item is relevant at any particular time. So my question is, is there a collections API anywhere that would support retrieval on an object based on the key being passed being in a certain range.

An example is below

If I have some data that represents the below "times"

0.0
1.0
2.5
2.7
3.0

I want to be able to store the data such that if I pass in a key value I will get back the lowest matching value. Some example key values are below

0.7 will retrieve the 0.0 object
2.49 will retrieve the 1.0 object
2.7 will retrieve the 2.7 object
10.0 will retrieve the 3.0 object

I am fully aware I could probably code up something myself but I wanted to check if any API's already existed which did this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want a NavigableSet (which is implemented by TreeSet) (or a NavigableMap, implemented by TreeMap). It has methods such as [`floor(E e)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#floor%28E%29):

> Returns the greatest element in this set less than or equal to the given element, or null if there is no such element.

Answer (score 3):

You can store your times in a `NavigableSet` and retrieve the data with `floor`.

```
NavigableSet<Double> timeSet = new TreeSet<Double>();
timeSet.add(0.0);
timeSet.add(1.0);
timeSet.add(2.5);
timeSet.add(2.7);
timeSet.add(3.0);

System.out.println(timeSet.floor(0.7));
System.out.println(timeSet.floor(2.49));
```

In case you need data to your times, there is also a `NavigableMap` (e.g. `TreeMap`) with the method `floorEntry` to retrieve the data.